# efficient distance calculations in armadillo

Tags: c++, r, rcpp, armadillo

I'm new to armadillo. I have the below code, which I assume is inefficient. Any suggestions to make it more memory efficient and/or speedy? Following the [armadillo docs](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html) and [Rcpp gallery](http://gallery.rcpp.org/tags/armadillo/), I was unable to get `.colptr`'s, `uvec`'s, or batch insertion to work. But I assume any of them would be improvements.

With an input of `X` (~100 x 30000), even my stupidly large work VM crashes.

```
Linux release 7.3.1611 (Core)
117GB RAM / 0GB SWAP
(24 x 2.494 GHz) processor(s)

R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: CentOS Linux 7 (Core)
```

#### code

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]

using namespace Rcpp;
using namespace arma;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
sp_mat arma_distmat_LT(const arma::mat& x) { // input expected X_{n x p} n << p
  int nr, nc;
  Col<double> col0, col1;

  nr = x.n_rows;
  nc = x.n_cols;

  sp_mat out(nc, nc);
  for (int i = 0; i < nc; i++) {
    col0 = x.col(i);
    for (int j = i + 1; j < nc; j++) {
      col1 = x.col(j);
      out(j, i) = as_scalar(col0.t() * col1);
    }
  }
  return out;
}
```

Call: `sourceCpp("<file>"); dist_x <- arma_distmat_LT(X)`

*Note:* these are distances because I am calculating cosine similarities where I have set L2 norm == 1.

Comment: "With an input of X (~100 x 30000), even my stupidly large work VM crashes. " The VM crashes? Or just get's hung up on the call. Your nested for loop in this example is going to iterate 30,000 x 30,000 = 900,000,000 times. This is not a trivial amount of work. Also, your code is single threaded so it does not matter if you have 24 processors or just 1, it still is stuck by the 2.494 GHz clock speed.

Comment: Consider possibly parallelizing your for loops, like this example: http://www.alecjacobson.com/weblog/?p=4544

Comment: Rather than transpose `col0` all the time, you can store `x.col(j).t()` in a variable and use that.

Comment: 1201ProgramAlarm duh--good point. @mascoj: correct. I tent to parallelize in R vs openMP. So any parallelization would be a wrapper of the serialized code--thank you for the example

Comment: This question is better suited for codereview as this code already works...

Comment: @coatless ... codereview? ooh, cool. never knew of that stackexchange site. I'm happy to receive a migration flag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me as if you're just computing the (upper triangular) matrix product `t(X)%*%X`. You can actually do that directly in R with the underused `crossprod` function.

```
X <- matrix(rnorm(100*30000), ncol=30000)
res <- crossprod(X, X)
```

This takes a few minutes on my laptop. If you change your code to use the Armadillo library then you can use

```
sp_mat arma_distmat_LT2(const arma::mat& x) { // input expected X_{n x p} n << p                               
  int nr, nc;
  Col<double> col0, col1;

  nr = x.n_rows;
  nc = x.n_cols;

  sp_mat out(nc, nc);
  out = trimatl(x.t() * x, k=-1);
  return out;
}
```

Still takes a few minutes. It uses an awful amount of memory though so I doubt you can have a lot of objects in memory at the same time.

The code could probably be optimized to only compute the lower/upper triangular matrix.

---

Just to show the speedup for a 100*800 matrix:

```
> microbenchmark(crossprod(X, X), arma_distmat_LT(X), arma_distmat_LT2(X))
Unit: milliseconds
                expr        min         lq       mean     median         uq
     crossprod(X, X)   50.25574   53.72049   57.98812   56.29532   58.71277
  arma_distmat_LT(X) 1331.83243 1471.42465 1523.74060 1492.84611 1512.45416
 arma_distmat_LT2(X)   29.69420   33.23954   36.24613   35.54700   38.05208
        max neval cld
  160.81227   100  a 
 3080.37891   100   b
   66.07351   100  a
```

As you can see there is a substantial speedup to be gained by brute-forcing it. That being said I'm sure that the cross product can be optimised further.

Comment: You are correct. That's exactly what I'm doing. thanks... Am I correct that this calculates the full dense matrix then `trimatl` subsets 1/2 of it? If so, that strikes me as highly inefficient

Comment: Yes. The "benefit" is in being able to use the optimised routines directly. We are calculating twice the necessary number of elements needed but it is runnable without crashing. I've added the timing speedup to the answer

Comment: I have accepted, but would prefer to change the accepted answer to one that calculates the LT or UT directly (without the duplicate calculations)... Of note, I suggest you edit your answer to `trimatl(..., k = -1)` to avoid the storing the unnecessary diagonal of 1's.

Comment: @Alex I totally agree. Tinkering away with trying to get a speed boost and only make the necessary computations. Have updated the answer